# Why is Docker not binding my volumes to the container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a very simple project:

Dockerfile:

```
from node:lts

VOLUME /scripts
WORKDIR /scripts

RUN bash -c 'ls /'
RUN bash -c 'ls /scripts'

RUN script.sh
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
    service:
        build: .
        volumes:
            - .:/scripts
```

Then I run `docker-compose build` but it fails with `/bin/sh: 1: script.sh: not found`

From the `ls /scripts` I can see that Docker isn't binding my script to the container. I have Docker `19.03.8`. Do you know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: you are not copying your local files to the volume. You have to add the COPY attribute on your Dockerfile pointing to the directory where you've got the script.

Answer (score 0):

When you run a Docker Compose file, the `build:` block is run first, and it ignores all of the options outside that block.  A Dockerfile never has mounted volumes, it can never make network calls to other Compose containers, and it won't see `environment:` variables that are set elsewhere.

That means you must explicitly `COPY` code into your image before you can `RUN` it.

```sh
FROM node:ls
WORKDIR /scripts
COPY script.sh .
RUN ./script.sh
```